# 17.04 - Can't install downloaded .deb files from Ubuntu Software

Tags: apt, software-center, 17.04

When I double click the `.deb` file it opens up in the Ubuntu Software app.

However, clicking the "Install" button doesn't do anything - no popups or errors, like I didn't even click it.

I can install the packages from the terminal by running

```
sudo dpkg -i *package_name*
sudo apt-get install -f
```

But I'd like to have my Ubuntu Software fixed. Any ideas?

Comment: Install `gdebi` package, then try double clicking on `deb` files.

Comment: @EODCraftStaff fix is released already https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1672424

Comment: Now 16.04.1 LTS is affected too (after regular update).

Comment: Don't forget to set `gdebi` as the default for opening `deb` files before double-clicking, otherwise it will just open in Ubuntu Software Center again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use gdebi to install packages.
How to install:

```
sudo apt install gdebi
```

Solved the problem for me.

Comment: I guess that there is no other way for now, i tried a lot of stuff but i couldn't fix it.... Gdebi appears to be working fine for now.

Comment: yes, i guess they are working on a fix.

Comment: To open and install the `deb` file using `gdebi` via double-clicking the file, you'll need to set `gdebi` as the default application for opening `deb` files: Right-click a `deb` file, click Properties, then the Open With tab and select Gdebi from the list of applications.